# Cant work out method overloading

Tags: c

Im trying to overload the *FindCost* method in *PurchasedItem* with a new method in the *FreshItem* subclass. The new *FreshItem* *FindCost* method uses weight instead of quantity to determine the cost.

Im getting errors :

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'gItem'
>
> 'Program.GroceryItem.PurchasedItem.FreshItem.FindCost()' hides inherited member 'Program.GroceryItem.PurchasedItem.FindCost()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

How would I allow the *FreshItem* *FindCost* method to be used if the item is fresh?

```
    class Program
    {
        public class GroceryItem
        {
        public string Name;
        public double Price;

        public PurchasedItem pItem
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public GroceryItem()
        {
        }

        public GroceryItem(string name, double price)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Price = price;
        }
        public class PurchasedItem
        {
            public int Quantity;
            GroceryItem item;
            public PurchasedItem(GroceryItem gItem)
            {
                item = new GroceryItem(gItem.Name, gItem.Price);
            }

            public double FindCost()
            {
                return item.Price * this.Quantity * 1.10;
            }

            public class FreshItem : PurchasedItem
            {
                public FreshItem() 
                {
                }
                public double weight;

                public double FindCost()
                {
                    return this.item.Price * this.weight;
                }

            }
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var item1 = new GroceryItem("Lettuce", 2.05);
            item1.pItem = new GroceryItem.PurchasedItem(item1);
            item1.pItem.Quantity = 12;
            double cost1 = item1.pItem.FindCost();


            Console.WriteLine(item1.Name + " " + item1.Price);
            Console.WriteLine(cost1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
FreshItem : PurchasedItem
```

So you are inheriting `PurchasedItem.FindCost` but you also have the `FindCost` method in `FreshItem` so you get this error which is really clear and complains about what you did above:

> Program.GroceryItem.PurchasedItem.FreshItem.FindCost()' hides inherited member 'Program.GroceryItem.PurchasedItem.FindCost()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

To fix this error, you can declare the `PurchasedItem.FindCost` as virtual so you can then override it:

```
public virtual double FindCost()
```

Then in the `FreshItem`, override it:

```
public override double FindCost()
```

For the other error, see the answer from @MazaherBazari.

Answer (score 3):

When base class has constructor with parameter you should call it explicity.
it must be:

```
public FreshItem():base(/*pass paramter*/)
{
}
```

See: [Derived class explicit base constructor call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979260/derived-class-explicit-base-constructor-call)

And for your second problem `PurchasedItem` and `FreshItem` must inherit from  `GroceryItem` and implement `FindMethod`:

```
public abstract class GroceryItem
    {
    public string Name {set;get;}
    public double Price {set;get;}

    public GroceryItem(string name, double price){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public abstract double FindCost();
}
public class PurchasedItem: GroceryItem
{
    public int Quantity {set;get;}
    public PurchasedItem(string name, double price, int quntity):base(name, price)
    {
      this.Quantity = quntity;
    }

    public override double FindCost()
    {
        return this.Price * this.Quantity * 1.10;
    }


}
public class FreshItem : GroceryItem
{
    public double Weight {set;get;}

    public FreshItem(string name, double price, int weight) : base(name, price)
    {
        this.Weight= weight;
    }
    public override double FindCost()
    {
        return this.Price * this.Weight;
    }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var item1 = new PurchasedItem("Lettuce", 2.05,12);
    double cost1 = item1.FindCost();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix first error use Mazaher Bazari answer

but your code still won't work like you want

try fix like this

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item1 = new GroceryItem("Lettuce", 2.05);
        item1.pItem = new FreshItem(item1);
        item1.pItem.Quantity = 12;
        double cost1 = item1.pItem.FindCost();


        Console.WriteLine(item1.Name + " " + item1.Price);
        Console.WriteLine(cost1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class PurchasedItem
{
    public int Quantity;
    protected GroceryItem item;
    public PurchasedItem(GroceryItem gItem)
    {
        item = new GroceryItem(gItem.Name, gItem.Price);
    }

    public virtual double FindCost()
    {
        return item.Price * this.Quantity * 1.10;
    }


}
public class FreshItem : PurchasedItem
{
    public double weight;

    public FreshItem(GroceryItem gItem) : base(gItem)
    {
    }

    public override double FindCost()
    {
        return this.item.Price * this.weight;
    }

}
public class GroceryItem
{
    public string Name;
    public double Price;

    public PurchasedItem pItem
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public GroceryItem()
    {
    }

    public GroceryItem(string name, double price)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }
}
```

you should add `Virtual` and `Override` to override method if not you need to new instance as FreshItem to use FreshItem FindCost